# ORA-02201: sequence not allowed here with Hibernate @SequenceGenerator

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence

I get the following error:

```
error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
...
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
...
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02201: sequence not allowed here
```

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "mytable", schema = "myschema")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name="mygenerator", sequenceName = "myschema.myseq",allocationSize = 1)
public class MYENTITY {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mygenerator")
private Long id;
}
```

The sequence "myseq" exists.

Any clue, why I get the error?

Hibernate Dialect: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.asb.anna.web.repository.Oracle12cDialectBugfixImpl

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: `ORA-` error means Oracle, which is also [tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) @crizzis

Comment: You'll have to post the statement that is causing the exception. Basically the error means the generated query violates some [Restrictions on Sequence Values](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF50944)

Comment: @mcflysoft  What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: I added the dialect to the question. Maybe that the problem?